# Is multivariable function differentiable at $0$?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Let $f:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^n$ be defined by
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}\dfrac{x}{\|x\|},&x\neq0\\0,&x=0.\end{cases}$$
Is $\space f \space$ differentiable at $\space 0$?

Using the definition we need to check if
$$0=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(h)-Bh}{|h|}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\frac{h}{\|h\|}-Bh}{|h|}$$
Im not sure what to do next or how to get a contradiction.

Comment: For function to be differentiable, it first must be continuous. This function is not: $\|f(0)\|=0$, but $\lim_{x \to 0}\|f(x)\|=1$.

Comment: The limit as $x\to 0$ does not make sense in this case. But one can take a limit as $x\to 0+$ along one of the coordinate axes. That will be 1. indeed.

Comment: For your future work: If such a $B$ exists, it must be the matrix of partial derivatives of $f$ at the origin. Does this function have partial derivatives at the origin?

Answer (score 1):

For $n=1$ the function is not even continuous. It is $-1$ for $x<0$, $1$ for $x>0$ and $0$ for $x=0$. For $n>1$ the function is not continuous for the same reason.

Comment: But $x$ is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: I said "for the same reason".

Comment: Oh, okay!  Thanks for clarifying that.  I guess I missed the "for $n=1$".  Right, when $n=1$ we can talk about $x$ being posiitive or negative.